# Sort List in Dictionary's Value

Tags: c#

i am working on assignment where i define following dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<fileInfo>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<fileInfo>>();
```

where

```
public class fileInfo
    {
        public string fileFullName;
        public double tf;
        public double idf;
        public double tf_idf;
        public double cosineSim;

        public fileInfo()
        {
            fileFullName = null;
            tf = 0.0;
            idf = 0.0;
            tf_idf = 0.0;
            cosineSim = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

now i want to sort the list with respect to COSINESIM

Comment: So do it, googling will take less time than asking questions on SO. First post in related is exactly what you want.

Comment: Any code that you tried to do?

Comment: I'm all about helping others... but oh my, you show complete lack of any effort in solving your homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a combined (merged) list of fileInfo sorted by cosineSim you can use Dmitry's answer.

Else if you want to order the items in each list in your dictionary you can use

```
myDic.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.OrderBy(fi => fi.cosineSim).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a *combined (merged) list* of `fileInfo` sorted by `cosineSim` you can do

```
  List<fileInfo> result = myDic.Values
    .SelectMany(item => item)        // amalgamating all the lists   
    .OrderBy(item => item.cosineSim) // ordering the result
    .ToList();
```

In case you want to sort *each* list *within* `myDic` dictionary, just `Sort` them:

```
  foreach(var list in myDic.Values)
    list.Sort(Comparer<fileInfo>.Create((left, right) => 
      left.cosineSim.CompareTo(right.cosineSim)));
```

Comment: I really thank full "my Teacher": i work on it for last connective 5 to 6 hr but all in vain.... you really solved my problem